# Do books serve any purpose?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Do the books that I've been randomly looting off bookshelves serve any purpose other then reading for the lore and then selling? How about random invoices, tattered documents, letters, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bookworm achievement requires you to read 50 books throughout the world.

Additionally, there are certain books scattered throughout the world that give permanent skill bonuses (e.g. Lockpicking, Stealth, Blacksmithing, etc). These books, however, are generally labeled appropriately, such as Skill Book: Lockpicking.

Lastly, there is at least one (if not multiple) collection quest(s) that require you to get books as part of the collection.

Comment: Found one other thing. There's a bookshelf in Gorhart (in the reliquary) where you have to find ten books that belong to a priest. The quest is triggered by trying to loot the bookshelf. Thanks for the answer :) I'll accept it, but maybe edit in that some are needed as quest items.

Comment: @spugley Ah yes, I did find that quest as well. I didn't think of it because the bookshelf itself showed up as a quest on my minimap. I've only retrieved one of them so far, and I didn't actually look to see if the item was a book or just a basic quest object. I will edit it in however, fair point.

Answer (score 5):

Reading books will contribute towards the Bookworm achievement which requires you to read 50 of them.